# Does $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left|c_m g(x)^{2m+1}\right|$ converge absolutely to an integrable function?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t}J_1(f(t)-f(s))\mathop{ds}=\int_{0}^{t}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_m (f(t)-f(s))^{2m+1}\mathop{ds},
\end{equation}
such that $J_1$ is the Bessel function of first kind and order, $f(t)\in\mathbb{R}$, and
\begin{equation}
c_m=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{2m+1}\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(m+2)}.
\end{equation}
If $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_m (f(t)-f(s))^{2m+1}$ exists for all $s$, and there is an integrable function
\begin{equation}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \left|c_m (f(t)-f(s))^{2m+1}\right|\geq\left|\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_m (f(t)-f(s))^{2m+1}\right|,
\end{equation}
then the integration and summation symbols may be swapped in the first equation. So, is there a way to show that this sum converges to an integrable function? Any help would be much appreciated.

We also may assume that
\begin{equation}
    f(t)^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \alpha_{k,n} t^n,
\end{equation}
and is differentiable/integrable for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (including $0$) such that $\alpha_{k,n}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The answer is no without further assumptions on $f$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis What further assumptions on $f$ would be required to make the answer yes?

Comment: The boundedness of $f$ will certainly be enough. What can **you** say about your $f$?

Comment: I can say that $f$ is ergodic, if that helps. I think boundedness would be fine in certain situations (i.e. specific values of $\kappa$ and $\beta$). The integro-differential equation $\kappa \ddot{f}+\dot{f}=\beta\int_{0}^t J_1(f_t-f_s)e^{s-t}\mathop{ds}$ describes $f$ for real constants (but I'm interested in analysing the integral for a more general $f$).